# Reference Request: Modulus of Continuity of Matrix Multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, matrix-equations

Let $M:GL_n\times \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$; equip $\mathbb{R}^n$ with its usual Euclidean topology and $GL_n$ with its relative Euclidean topology (from the Frobenius norm).  Is the modulus of continuity of this function known?

Comment: What is this function?  Evaluating a matrix on a column vector?  And what is the modulus of continuity?

Comment: Are you familiar with the inequalities $\|A\|\le \|A\|_2 \le \sqrt n\|A\|$, where $\|A\|$ is the operator norm (so $|Ax|\le \|A\||x|$) and $\|A\|_2$ is the Frobenius norm? If not, prove them :P

Comment: Does the second one have a name?  I can prove it but I would like to cite it for a result